# AJAX Request returning "Invalid Parameter", Request works without proxy

Tags: ajax, proxy, request

I am trying to do an ajax request to read xml from a server. I am using a proxy to do so. If i enter the request directly in the browser, it returns the correct XML. When I use my proxy, it returns "Invalid Parameter." Any idea?

Proxy.PHP

```
<?php
$c = file_get_contents((urldecode($_REQUEST['u'])));
$content_type = 'Content-Type: text/plain';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($http_response_header); $i++) {
    if (preg_match('/content-type/i',$http_response_header[$i])) {
        $content_type = $http_response_header[$i];
    }
}
if ($c) {
    header($content_type);
    echo $c;
}
else {
    header("content-type: text/plain");
    echo 'There was an error satisfying this request.';
}
?>
```

request:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url:  'proxy.php?u=' + 'http://192.168.100.147:8080/thredds/sos/cfpoint/timeSeriesProfile-Ragged-MultipeStations-H.5.3/timeSeriesProfile-Ragged-MultipeStations-H.5.3.nc?request=GetObservation&service=SOS&version=1.0.0&responseFormat=text%2Fxml%3B%20subtype%3D%22om%2F1.0.0%22&offering=urn:tds:station.sos:Station1&procedure=urn:tds:station.sos:Station1&observedproperty=temperature&eventTime=1990-01-01T00:00:00Z/1990-01-01T00:00:00Z',
        dataType: "xml",
        success: parseSOSGetObs,
        error: function () {alert("AJAX ERROR for " + capRequest );}
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the information you've given, I would guess that the server is expecting more data in your header or cookie data.  When scraping data on Ajax pages it is better to use the Curl Library instead of file_get_contents().
When you enter the request directly into the browser, use the Net option in firefox firebug extension to see exactly what is being passed in the headers.  Copy those headers and set them in CURL.  If that doesn't work, it could be a cookie issue.  Have CURL visit the original page, store the cookies and use them for the second request..

Ex:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "/tmp/COOKIE");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://originalsite.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:9.0a2) Gecko/20111101 Firefox/9.0a2");
$junk = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);


$headers = array("X-Prototype-Version: 1.6.0", "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest");
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "/tmp/COOKIE");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/tmp/COOKIE");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://originalsite.com/setsomething.sync");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://originalsite.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:9.0a2) Gecko/20111101 Firefox/9.0a2");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

I forgot:  You can use the CURLOPT_PROXY option in CURL to set the proxy